# RevMob banner covers action sheet

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactionsheet, banner, revmob

I have a small problem when trying to implement `RevMob` ads into my app. I am showing a banner, but for some reason when an action sheet is brought up from the bottom of the screen, it is covered by the `RevMob` banner. Is there a way to get around this issue? I could not find any question related to this..

I don't want to hide it as it has a nice hiding animation and I would have to wait for that animation to finish before actually showing the action sheet, making the app look like it is freezing before showing the action sheet.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a `RevMobBannerView` instead of a `RevMobBanner`. The nice animations are gone though..